# How to detect one button press?

Tags: verilog, counter

I have a stopwatch circuit running on a nexys4 where I can control it with a start, stop and reset button. So if I click start, the counter starts counting until stop or reset it hit. I'm trying to add a feature where when I press another button, the counter increments by only 1 bit. Right now the clock is too fast, so when I press the increment button, it increments multiple times over because it is detecting the button press at each clock edge. How do I have it register only ONE button press, no matter how long I hold the button down? Do I need a debouncer circuit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a rising edge detector and some debounce logic.
I'll start you with the rising edge detector because that will solve most of the problem.

```
reg [3:0] resync;
reg       inc_cntr;
always @ (posedge clk)
begin 
   resync <= {resync[2:0],inc_btn};  // This will clock in the inc_btn signal and remove metastability.
   inc_cntr <= ~resync[3] & resync[2]; // Only high when the resync[3] was low and resent[2] is high.  
end
```

What this doesn't solve is if your button bounces a lot as the transition from up to down occurs.  Take a look at this to understand debounce.  [Switch Debouncing](https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs270/270lab/270_docs/debounce.html)

Between these two topics, you should be able to work out a good push button filter.

Comment: So if I'm detecting the button presses with a state machine and sending the output state to a counter to tell it what to do (either count up, stop, or increment), where would this go? Could I just throw it in the state machine? Or should I do it as it's own module and when the increment button is pressed, send that to this module (with the debouncer) and send the output to the counter telling it to increment by one? Here is a basic block diagram how it works: http://imgur.com/a/b7iOe (controller holds the state machine)

Comment: Ok I got it working besides the debouncer! Would the debouncer go directly after the "inc_cntr <= ~resync[3] & resync[2]" line or would it be its own module?

Comment: I would make your debouncer a separate module as you could probably reuse it on your next button project.  I would debounce after the synchronizer.  So booking to inc_cntr pulse would be good.   You don't want the debouncer going meta stable and the syncronizer will protect against that.

Comment: So currently I have the synchronizer in the state machine where button presses are detected. I should send the output the inc_cntr to a debouncer and then the output of the debouncer to the binary counter, correct?

Comment: What you suggest I believe will work.  As you get into this, you will find that there are lots of ways to skin the cat, but as a rule...eliminate META stability first.  For newbies, I'll go as far as to say, NEVER EVER UNDER CIRCUMSTANCE, pass a non synchronized signal directly into a state machine.  [Sync -> debounce -> state-machine] is a known good working pattern.  Remember that in most cases, the debouncer is a state machine too...which is why you want to sync first.

Comment: @user2817437 if you like the answer, don't forget accept it as the answer. Thx.